# itext7 pdf to image

Tags: itext, itextpdf

I am using iText7(java) and am looking for  a way to convert a pdf page to image. 
In older iText versions you could do this :

```
PdfImportedPage page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, 1);
Image image = Image.getInstance(page);
```

But iText7 does not have PdfImportedPage .

My use case, I have a one page pdf file. I need to add a table and resize the pdf contents to fit a single page. In old iText I would create a page , add table, convert existing pdf page to image, resize image and add that resized image to new page. Is there a new way to do this in iText7.

Thanks to Bruno's answer I got this working with following code :

```
PdfPage origPage = readerDoc.getPage(1);
Rectangle rect = origPage.getPageSize();
Document document = new Document(writerDoc);
Table wrapperTable = new Table(1);
Table containerTable = new Table(new float[]{0.5f,0.5f});
containerTable.setWidthPercent(100);
containerTable.addCell( "col1");
containerTable.addCell("col2");

PdfFormXObject pageCopy = origPage.copyAsFormXObject(writerDoc);
Image image = new Image(pageCopy);
image.setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
image.setAutoScale(true);
image.setHeight(rect.getHeight()-250);
wrapperTable.addCell(new Cell().add(containerTable).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
wrapperTable.addCell(new Cell().add(image).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
document.add(wrapperTable);
document.close();
readerDoc.close();
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Please read the official documentation for iText 7, more specifically [Chapter 6: Reusing existing PDF documents](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/chapter-6-reusing-existing-pdf-documents)

In PDF, there's the concept of *Form XObject*s. A *Form XObject* is a piece of PDF content that is stored outside the content stream of a page, hence XObject which stands for eXternal Object. The use of the word *Form* in *Form XObject* could be confusing, because people might be thinking of a form as in a fillable form with fields. To avoid that confusing, we introduced the term `PdfTemplate` in iText 5.

The class `PdfImportedPage` you refer to was a subclass of `PdfTemplate`: it was a piece of PDF syntax that could be reused in another page. Over the years, we noticed that people also got confused by the word `PdfTemplate`.

In iText 7, we returned to the basics. When talking about a Form XObject, we use the class `PdfFormXObject`. When talking about a page in a PDF file, we use the class `PdfPage`.

This is how we get a `PdfPage` from an existing document:

```
PdfDocument origPdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(src));
PdfPage origPage = origPdf.getPage(1);
```

This is how we use that page in a new document:

```
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
PdfFormXObject pageCopy = origPage.copyAsFormXObject(pdf);
```

If you want to use that `pageCopy` as an `Image`, just create it like this:

```
Image image = new Image(pageCopy);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the info .

Comment: Can somebody specify in which namespace does this "Image" class above exists?

Comment: @woohoo In Java: [com.itextpdf.layout.element.Image](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/iText7/latest/com/itextpdf/layout/element/Image.html); In C#: `iText.Layout.Element.Image`. Please consult the [Java API docs](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/iText7/latest/) or the [C# tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/sharp/chapter-1-introducing-basic-building-blocks) where all of these basic questions are answered. **Important:** I am assuming that you are using iText 7.

Comment: How to set this image to picturebox?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie, Can you please post a sample of how to save the converted pdf as a png image file?

Comment: It can be late but, they have PdfRender for Java now https://www.pdfa.org/new-product-release-convert-pdf-to-images-with-itext-pdfrender/. Soon there will be for C#, but use Apitron instead to do that job in C#. Here is an example: https://github.com/apitron/Apitron.PDF.Rasterizer.Samples/blob/master/ConvertPDFtoBitmap/Program.cs