# iText7 Convert PDF to Image

Tags: c#, itext7

Please let me know what method can be used to convert pdf to image  in iText7. 
In Itexsharp, there was an option to convert pdf file to images. Following is the link. PDF to Image Using iTextSharp
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/a0927b/create-pdf-document-and-convert-to-image-programmatically/

Below is the sample code created using the following refernce link.
[itext7 pdf to image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37809019/itext7-pdf-to-image)
this is not working as expected. It is not converting the pdf to image. It is creating a 1kb blank image.

```
string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(inputFilePath);
var pdfReader = new PdfReader(inputFilePath);
var pdfDoc = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(pdfReader);
int pagesLength = pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages()+1;
for (int i = 1; i < pagesLength; i++)
{
    if (!File.Exists(System.IO.Path.Combine(imageFileDir, fileName + "_" + 
 `enter code here`(startIndex + i) + ".png")) && i < pagesLength)
    {

        PdfPage pdfPages = pdfDoc.GetPage(i);
        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(System.IO.Path.Combine(imageFileDir, fileName + "_" + (startIndex + i) + ".png"), new WriterProperties().SetFullCompressionMode(true));
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
        PdfFormXObject pageCopy = pdfPages.CopyAsFormXObject(pdf);
        iText.Layout.Element.Image image = new iText.Layout.Element.Image(pageCopy);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your first link does not use iText to convert a pdf to an image. Your second link does.

Comment: Also: you are using the `PdfWriter` class to create a file with extension `.png`. You can't create a PNG file with a `PdfWriter` instance. I'd even say more: you can't create a PNG file with iText. iText **does not** convert PDFs to raster images (such as .jpg, .png,...). You are misinterpreting the examples that create an `Image` instance based on an existing page. Those examples create an XObject that can be reused in a new PDF *as if it were a vector image*; they don't convert a PDF page to a raster image.

Answer (score 4):

Quoting Bruno:

> iText does not convert PDFs to raster images (such as .jpg, .png,...). You are misinterpreting the examples that create an Image instance based on an existing page. Those examples create an XObject that can be reused in a new PDF as if it were a vector image; they don't convert a PDF page to a raster image.

What you can use for this (which is what we at iText internally use for testing) is GhostScript. It takes a pdf as input and converts it to a series of images (one image per page).