# How can I get images from a PDF file?

Tags: itext7

I put some images to a PDF file. And Now, I want to get this images from PDF file use itext7. How to get images from PDF?

Comment: *"I put some images to a PDF file."* - how? Have you added them as file attachments? If yes, at document level or at page level? Or have you added them to some page content? Or some annotation content?

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37809019/itext7-pdf-to-image

Comment: @GaganV That answer is specifically about using a pdf page as an image. Which does not seem to be what the user ultimately wants.

Answer (score 5):

The idea would be to use `IEventListener` to process each page, and have the `IEventListener` implementation do something whenever it encounters an image.

```
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(inputFle));

ImageExtractor imgs = new ImageExtractor();
PdfCanvasProcessor pdfCanvasProcessor = new PdfCanvasProcessor(imgs);
pdfCanvasProcessor.processPageContent(pdfDocument.getPage(1));

pdfDocument.close();

for(BufferedImage bi : imgs.getImages()){
    // TODO : enter your image handling code here 
}
```

Of course, you would still need to write ImageExtractor to process the incoming page.

```
class ImageExtractor implements IEventListener{

    private List<BufferedImage> imgs = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void eventOccurred(IEventData data, EventType type) {
        if(type != EventType.RENDER_IMAGE)
            return;

        ImageRenderInfo img = (ImageRenderInfo) data;
        try {
            imgs.add(img.getImage().getBufferedImage());
        } catch (IOException e) {}
    }

    public List<BufferedImage> getImages(){ return imgs; }

    @Override
    public Set<EventType> getSupportedEvents() { return null; }

}
```